# How to put a ProgresBar in front of my ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

I have the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_ui_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        facebook:confirm_logout="false"
        facebook:fetch_user_info="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.26"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />


</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to put a ProgresBar in front (or on top, depends how yo see it) of my ImageView.

Please how do I achieve this??

*This is the desired result:*

[image]

Comment: Use a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout...

Comment: @Frohnzie please how would I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RelativeLayouts allow items to "stack" on top of each other, which is what you are looking for.

Thus you can wrap your LinearLayout in a RelativeLayout, and add a ProgressBar to the Relative Layout like so:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_ui_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- Primary content -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```